# How can I retrieve meta information about synonym matches for a Solr query?

Tags: search, solr, faceted-search, synonym

We are using Solr to provide search functionality for our site, and I have the following requirement which has me stumped:

Given the search term "2011 Bolinger", identify that "Bollinger" (note the different spelling) is a valid value for the Producer facet, and automatically apply facet filtering for this value.

It's the fuzzy matching of the search term which I'm stuck on. Does anyone know of a way to include information in a Solr response about synonym matches which have occurred for a query during the search (i.e. a way for Solr to tell me that it saw the word 'Bollinger' in a document and recognised it as equivalent to 'Bolinger')? From what I've read so far of the Solr documentation I can't see a way to do this, but I may have missed something.

Comment: this questions could have been asked in 3 lines. Advice: many people will ignore your question after seeing its length!

Comment: I was trying to be thorough, but I see your point. I have trimmed my question - hope that's better!